# Jenkins - how to show downstream jobs build result on Gerrit patch set?

Tags: jenkins, gerrit, gerrit-trigger

below is my use case,

I have jobs A, B, C - A is upstream and B and C are downstream jobs. When a Patch set created in Gerrit, based on the `patchset created event` I trigger `Job A` and based on the result of this job, we trigger B and C. After the B and C is executed, I want to display the result of all three jobs on Gerrit patch set. like

```
 Job A SUCCESS
 JOB B SUCCESS
 JOB C FAILED
```

right now I see only `JOB A` Build result showing up on GERRIT PATCH SET as

```
 JOB A SUCCESS
```

is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Do the following:

1) Configure all jobs (A, B and C) to trigger when the patch set is created.

2) Configure the jobs B and C to depend on job A

2.1) Click on "Advanced..." in Gerrit Trigger job configuration

[image]

2.2) Add the job A on the "Other jobs on which this job depends" field

[image]

With this configuration jobs B and C will wait for job A finish before they start and you'll get the result you want:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.. When I use trigger for all A,B and C jobs, all 3 execute at once based on the trigger right? and I am using JJB (jenkins job builder) to create job configurations. I don't see this option in https://docs.openstack.org/infra/jenkins-job-builder/triggers.html?highlight=gerrit%20trigger#triggers.gerrit

Comment: The 3 will execute but the B and C will stay "pending" waiting for A to start. The option is there: dependency-jobs. Just set it and have fun :-)

Comment: Thank you Marcelo Ávila de Oliveira. Below is the observation on the above setup:

Comment: I have created A (upstr), B (Downstr) jobs and B is depends on (for now ignore job C) A. In Job B, I have given JOB A as dependency job, after a gerrit event is triggered on the patch, I see both JOB A and JOB B are triggered but JOB B waited till the JOB A is finished.. next irrespective of the JOB A result, JOB B continued to build.

What I am expecting here is, Job A should trigger based on the event, based on the result, it should trigger the downstream jobs. After the build verification, Developer should see the Result of both upstream and downstream jobs on the Gerrit patch set.

Comment: I understand :-( It seems this gerrit-trigger plugin feature is not nice at this point.

Comment: Is it possible with this setup to fetch artifacts created by `helloworld-build-patchset-1` into `helloworld-build-patchset-2`?

Comment: @RBT, result of JobA is available as env. variable. So, you can check it on the start of JobB.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to solve this is to create a small wrapper pipeline job. Let name it Build_ABC.

Configure Build_ABC to trigger on the Gerrit event you wish. The job will be responsible for running the other 3 builds and in the event of any failures in these jobs your Build_ABC will fail and report this back to Gerrit. You will not be able to see immediately which job failed in your Gerrit message but you will be able to see in in your Jenkins pipeline overview.

In the below scripted pipeline script you see a pipeline that calls Build_A and waits for the result. If the build succeeds it will continue to execute Build B and C in parallel. In my example I made Build C failed which caused the whole pipeline job to fail.

---

This is a revised version of my fist answer and the script has grown a bit. As it is required to have the individual build results in the message posted to Gerrit the pipeline has been changed to catch the individual results and record them. If build A fails builds B+C will be skipped and the status will be skipped.
Next it is possible to use the [gerrit review](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/cmd-review.html) ssh command line tool to perform manual review. This way it is possible to have a custom message generated to include the individual build results. It looks like the screen shot below:

[image]

I haven't figured out how to make it a multi line comment but there is also an option to use json in the command line, have a look at that.

```
def build_a = "Skipped"
def build_b = "Skipped"
def build_c = "Skipped"
def build_result = "+1"

try {
  stage("A") {
    try {
      build( job: '/Peter/Build_A', wait: true)
      build_a = "Pass"
    } catch (e) {
        build_a = "Failed"
        // throw again or else the job to make the build fail
        // throwing here will prevent B+C from running
        throw e
    }
  }

  stage("After A") {
    parallel B: {
      try {
        build( job: '/Peter/Build_B', wait: true)
        build_b = "Pass"
      } catch (e) {
        build_b = "Failed"
        // throw again or else the job to make the build fail
        throw e
      }
    }, C: {
      try {
        build( job: '/Peter/Build_C', wait: true)
        build_c = "Pass"
      } catch (e) {
        build_c = "Failed"
        // throw again or else the job to make the build fail
        throw e
      }
    }
  }
} catch(e) {
  build_result = "-1"
  // throw again or else the job to make the build fail
  throw e
} finally {
  node('master') {
    // Perform a custom review using the environment vars
    sh "ssh -p ${env.GERRIT_PORT} ${env.GERRIT_HOST} gerrit review --verified ${build_result} -m '\"Build A:${build_a} Build B: ${build_a} Build C: ${build_c}\"' ${env.GERRIT_PATCHSET_REVISION}"
  }
}
```

Next you should configure the Gerrit trigger to ignore the results from Jenkins or else there will be a double vote.
[image]

One more advantage is that with the Ocean Blue plugin you can get a nice graphical representation, see below image, of your build and you can examine what went wrong by clicking on the jobs.

[image]

Comment: How did you set the gerrit-trigger in the 3 jobs? Have you verified the gerrit-trigger comments ("Job A SUCCESS", "Job B SUCCESS" and "Job C FAILED", in your example) in Gerrit?

Comment: JOB B:
**
- trigger:
    name: gerrit-trigger-patch-submitted-skip
    triggers:
      - gerrit:
          server-name: 'xxx'
          trigger-on:
            - patchset-created-event:
                exclude-drafts: 'false'
                exclude-trivial-rebase: 'false'
                exclude-no-code-change: 'false'
            - draft-published-event
            - comment-added-contains-event:
                comment-contains-value: 'recheck'
            - comment-added-contains-event:
              dependency-jobs: Job A
**

Comment: Is it possible to trigger a job based on the Build result? as per this, https://docs.openstack.org/infra/jenkins-job-builder/triggers.html?highlight=triggers#triggers.gerrit I don't see any such option. 

I use `comment-containes-value` option to trigger builds based on the comment provided in the patchset.

Comment: I am sorry, I missed the part of you wishing to display that Job C failed. The only message you will see is that the pipeline job failed. I a way you are only interested in the total result. One job fail is still all fail.

Comment: I have reworked the answer and it will now report to Gerrit the individual build results. It is a bit more complicate then the original answer, it is up to you if you think the complexity is worth it.

Comment: Uncletall, thanks for the detailed explanation and for the work. I use freestyle not the pipeline and I am restricted to use pipeline projects. Is there any way to do this using "freestyle project"

Comment: You can probably do the same. If you have one job trigger the next you can perform the gerrit review using ssh in JobC. If Job A or Job B fails you can also report it in there. A bit more trouble some but doable.