# Combine Gerrit trigger with additional stage

Tags: python, jenkins, gerrit

I have Jenkins job (job A) that used as Gerrit listener. this job invoking another job (job B) and wait for this job build results and return the status to Gerrit respectively.
so far so good.
Now, with all Gerrit change I wont (for example) to check syntax of all files in some directory (whit a simple python script).
I wonder if there is a way to combine this two task (job b and python script) in the same job (job A), so the status will reflect the results of the two tasks (job b and python script).

Is it possible to run this python script from the current job (A) in parallel to the invoked job (B) or even before the invoked job and then return the status to Gerrit according to this two task ?

I'm using the 'Gerrit Trigger' plug-in as Gerrit listener and the 'Trigger builds on remote/local jobs' to invoke job B.

Comment: Yes, it's possible, what is your problem?

Comment: well the problem was how to it. the initial idea was to run the new script from job A, but I decide to implement it in a separate job.

Comment: See if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47797550/jenkins-how-to-show-downstream-jobs-build-result-on-gerrit-patch-set/47798562#47798562